# C++ return to main

Tags: c++, qt-creator, program-entry-point

I want to be able to get back to the main.cpp file from another.  For example.

```
// Main.cpp
#include "Globals.h"

int main()
{
    otherFile();
}

// Globals.h

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool otherFile();

//otherFile.cpp
#include "Globals.h"

bool otherFile() 
{
    // do stuff
    // Here I want to be able to go back to the main.cpp file.
}
```

Sorry if my question makes no sense

Comment: It doesn't make sense because you don't have to do anything extra to get back to main().

Comment: Normally you do not need to do anything. main() calls otherFile() and then returns back to main() in Main.cpp. Perhaps add some details on what you want: Do you want to call another function from Main.cpp? Please update your code to show it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return` will return control to the caller, which in this case would be `main()` in main.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

if you create a function in main.cpp and add declaration to Globals.h, then you can call this function from otherFile.cpp.

If you don't need any statements after "do stuff", then your program logic automatically will return to the main(), because end of function call, so just add instructions after otherFile(); call in main, and they will be executed after this function.

You decalred otherFile() as returning bool, so put and end of your function `return true;` or `return false;`

Answer (score 1):

You will go back to main automatically when you finish the `otherFile()`, and in `main()` you will get the `return` of the `OtherFile()`.

Comment: @Pete: No, you cannot.  Or at least, you aren't supposed to be able to.  main may not be called recursively.  And since every function is, directly or indirectly, called by main, any call *to* main is recursive.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley You can declare a static variable and in its constructor call main, so you can call main. This constructor is called before main, so you can have a function that is not called from main (directly or indirectly).

Comment: @Felics: Good point.  However, it's still not legal.  §3.6.1.2 -- "The function main shall not be used (3.2) within a program. ..."